# How to Backup Database on Hive?

Tags: database, backup, hive, restore

Is there a way to backup an entire DB on HIVE like we do on MySQL using mysqldump?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

There is a project `TAwarehouse` which can be used for doing backups. I don't have much knowledge about it. U can find more details in these link.

[backup-hadoop-and-hive](https://github.com/TAwarehouse/backup-hadoop-and-hive)

[README](https://github.com/TAwarehouse/backup-hadoop-and-hive/blob/master/README.txt)